# How can I create a navigation property to an unrelated table in Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on a large legacy app and cannot at this time make changes to the tables in question.

I have two tables with no defined relationship.

Users
{
    UserId bigint
    ...
}

UserData
{
    UniqueID varchar(9) (0 padded on the left to fill out the column).
    ...
}

So UserID and UniqueID are the same value, but stored in different formats.  UserID might be 1 and UniqueID would then be 000000001.  There is one record in each table for each user.

The current solution fills the UserData object on the constructor of the User object.

Is there any way in code that I can make UserData a child of Users via a navigation property?  This is all read only, and no data will be changed.

Comment: I think that you can't .. why not change the column that you can change to match the other .. or even build another column

Comment: There are a lot of other things happening with imports and other pieces accessing it that can break if we are not VERY careful with what we are doing (I am not saying that they were built right, just that this is a complicated mess and we have been bitten before).  I ended up adding a computed column and used that to bind them together.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a computed column to one of the tables as that was the easiest thing I saw to undo if necessary.  I added it and then waited a while to see if it broke something else.  After a week or so of it being in place, I went forward with the code changes.